# How to get a specifict part of a string inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `List` :

```
Old_list =['orders_ce_deduped.01.csv','orders_ce_deduped.02.csv']
```

i need to get the `01` and `02` part and store that into another `list`
using `python`

```
new_list = ['01','02']
```

Comment: ``[o.split(".")[1] for o in Old_list]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your csv file names are consistent like your example('~~~.number.csv')

this would probably work

```
new_list = [i.split('.')[1] for i in Old_list]
```

Comment: You can also use `[-2]` (instead of `[1]`) to mean "second-last component".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    cur = i.split('.')[-2]
    new_list.append(cur)
print(new_list)
#Output
['01','02']
```

Comment: this is giving me `'csv', 'csv'`

Comment: if the file name always has 3 sections separated by a dot `.` index should be [1]

Comment: @Anti_cse51 Use [-2] instead of [-1]. As Pubudu Sitinamaluwa suggested, use [1] if the file format always contains only 3 sections

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for the digits within two periods (".XXX."), you can use regular expressions:

```py
import re

Old_list =['orders_ce_deduped.01.csv','orders_ce_deduped.02.csv']

pattern = re.compile(r"\.(\d+)\.")
new_list = [re.findall(pattern, string)[0] for string in Old_list]

print(new_list)

# Output
['01', '02']
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
Old_list =['orders_ce_deduped.01.csv','orders_ce_deduped.02.csv']
new_list = []

for i in range(len(Old_list)):
      new_list.append(Old_list[i][18:20])
print(new_list)
```

Method 2: List Comprehension

```
Old_list =['orders_ce_deduped.01.csv','orders_ce_deduped.02.csv']
new_list = []

[new_list.append(Old_list[i][18:20]) for i in range(len(Old_list))]
print(new_list)
```